# `vendor.add` doesn't expose dependencies to dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-python

Migrating a legacy project from 2.7 and Ubuntu 18.04 [piecemeal, Python 3.10 & 22.04 next… then Flask!] from vendored dependencies to `requirements.txt`. Removed dependencies from project root and enumerated them in my `requirements.txt`.

My `requirements.txt` contains `google-cloud-storage==1.44.0` and was `venv-2-7/bin/python -m pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` with a `appengine_config.py` in same dir as `app.yaml` with:

```py
# From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
import os

from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

How do I resolve this error? - Attempted `venv-2-7/bin/python -c 'import google.cloud.storage'` which worked, but:

```
$ venv-2-7/bin/python /google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host 127.0.0.1 .
```

Errors [from PyCharm & manually] with:

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage
```

EDIT0: Including more information [below] as per comment requests:

###### `app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
    
handlers:
- url: /1/account.*
  script: api_account.app

inbound_services:
- warmup

libraries: # Also tried removing this section entirely
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest

env_variables:
  PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY: 1

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
```

EDIT1: Tried both solutions independently and even together:

```py
import os
import sys

import pkg_resources
import google

if os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE"):
    sys.path.insert(0, os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE"])

for lib_dir in os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'), 'lib':
    sys.path.insert(0, lib_dir)
    google.__path__.append(os.path.join(lib_dir, 'google'))
    pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry(lib_dir)

import google.cloud.storage
```

Is there some trick with `from google.appengine.ext import vendor`, should I not be using `/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine` as my `GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE` env var?

EDIT2: I tried inlining [`google.appengine.ext.vendor`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/vendor) and calling it in the loop, which gave me a `ImportError: No module named google.cloud._helpers` error

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't really quite clear. Are you running Python 3 and still vendoring your library + using ```appengine_configy.py```?

Comment: Python 2.7 only. Later I will upgrade to 3.10.

Comment: Could be because the latest version of google-cloud-storage which you installed ONLY supports ```Python >=3.7``` - https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/

Comment: As I referenced, using this version https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/1.44.0/ which still supports 2.7.

Comment: I deployed a small py2.7 app with vendored `google-cloud-storage v1.44.0` such as yours, but could not see this error. You should add more context to the question, like your `app.yaml` file and the code importing the Cloud Storage library. Can you also check if you find the GCS package within your lib folder, and in `/lib/google/cloud/storage` as well? As a note, in your `appengine_config.py` both `vendor.add()` lines achieve the same, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to repro your error but believe you. From initial glance, it looks like your `appengine_config.py` is incomplete. This suffices when you have non-GCP 3P dependencies:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Set PATH to your libraries folder.
PATH = 'lib'
# Add libraries installed in the PATH folder.
vendor.add(PATH)
```

However, if your `requirements.txt` has GCP client libraries, e.g., `google-cloud-*`, your `appengine_config.py` needs to use `pkg_resources` to support their use:

```
import pkg_resources
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Set PATH to your libraries folder.
PATH = 'lib'
# Add libraries installed in the PATH folder.
vendor.add(PATH)
# Add libraries to pkg_resources working set to find the distribution.
pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry(PATH)
```

To bring in `pkg_resources`, you need to add `setuptools` and `grpcio` to your `app.yaml`, and to use `google-cloud-storage` specifically, you need to also add `ssl`:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: yes
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: grpcio
  version: latest
- name: setuptools
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

All of these 3P pkg games "go away" when you finally upgrade to Python 3 where your `requirements.txt` remains the same, but you delete `appengine_config.py` and replace your `app.yaml` with the following (if you're not serving static files):

```
runtime: python310
```

These same instructions can also be found in the App Engine documentation on the [migrating bundled services page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services#importing-the-client-library). That page basically says what I just did above for both Python 2 and 3.

<ADVERTISEMENT>

When you're ready to upgrade to Python 3 and/or get off App Engine bundled services (NDB, Task Queue [push & pull], Memcache, Blobstore, etc.) to standalone Cloud equivalents (Cloud NDB, Cloud Tasks [push] or Cloud Pub/Sub [pull], Cloud Memorystore, Cloud Storage (GCS), etc.), or switch to [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.run), I've produced (well, *still* producing) a [modernization migration series](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/modernizing-your-serverless-applications?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=CDR_wes_aap-serverless_modernizesvls_sms_201003) complete with code samples, codelab tutorials, and videos, all of which complement the [official migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services). You can find more info including links to all those resources as [its open source repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine). In particular, your inquiry covers GCS, and that migration is covered by "Module 16." [The Mod16 app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine/tree/master/mod16-cloudstorage) is a sample that works with GCS and is a migration of [its analog Mod15 app](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine/tree/master/mod15-blobstore) based on Blobstore.

</ADVERTISEMENT>

Comment: This solution did not work. Is there something I'm missing? - See my question for the edits.

Comment: 0) It "did not work:" share *what* didn't work, including the errors.
1) You're making things too complicated; there's no need for an `appengine_config.py` that complex; just use the one I provided (otherwise the "it" differs).
2) `GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE` isn't a supported environment variable; see [this list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/runtime#environment_variables_2) of supported ones.
3) It's a configuration file, so don't import the GCS client library there; do that in `main.py`
4) Suggest reducing what you deploy to a Hello World GCS app.

Comment: yeah I know, it keeps getting more complex (because I thought I was doing something wrong). The error I get is `ImportError: No module named google.cloud.storage`. Is there some way to reset the module search hierarchy? - Because it's not finding `six.py` now, even when it is clearly present in `sys.path`.

Comment: Again, reduce it to a Hello World app where `requirements.txt` only has `six` and `google-cloud-storage`, `appengine_config.py` only has the 5 lines from my version, and `main.py` only has `import six` and `from google.cloud import storage` plus whatever you use to return a 200. For a full sample, see https://github.com/googlecodelabs/migrate-python2-appengine/tree/master/mod16-cloudstorage

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error.

I used to have problems with `protobuf` (the error was somewhat similar to what you're getting for storage). The solution was to update the google namespace package. I tried the same solution now (for storage) and your error went away

Update the code in your `appengine_config.py` to

```
    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
    import google, os

    lib_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib')
    google.__path__.append(os.path.join(lib_dir, 'google'))

    vendor.add('lib')
```

After updating `appengine_config.py`, the line `import google.cloud.storage` no longer gives error of `No module named cloud.storage`.

Comment: This solution did not work. Is there something I'm missing? - See my question for the edits.

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried my own code i.e you added it to appengine_config.py and you were still getting exactly the same error as you were getting before? If you're getting a different error, please state it

Comment: Yes I am still getting the `No module named cloud.storage` error.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the following env variables - GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE. I printed my env variables and don't see it listed

Comment: I manually set them. To infer this see my answer, I did a big hack to set `appengine_python_sdk` from a Python object in the `os.environ`.

Comment: There's an environment variable for that - ```CLOUDSDK_PYTHON```.  Try this. Create a basic App just for 'Hello World'. Add your command for ```import google.cloud.storage```. Keep the contents of your ```lib``` folder. Use exactly what I have in ```appengine_config.py```. In your shell, first set the env variable ```CLOUDSDK_PYTHON``` and then try running your app with ```dev_appserver.py```

Comment: Regardless it's not working :\

Comment: What is your OS or Platform?

Comment: Locally I am running macOS 12.5 (21G72) with gcloud 400.0.0 (app-engine-python 1.9.101, app-engine-python-extras 1.9.96) on a freshly compiled and then `virutalenv`'d Python 2.7.18.

Answer (score 0):

Went nuclear with this solution, I hate this with a passion:

```py
import inspect
import io
import os.path
import site
import sys
from collections import deque
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import chain

from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
from functools import partial
from os import getcwd, listdir

import google
```

```py
site_packages = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(sys.executable)), get_python_lib(prefix="")
)
new_sys_path = [getcwd(), site_packages]

lib_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib")
new_sys_path.append(lib_dir)

appengine_python_sdk = (
    os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE"]
    if os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_APPENGINE")
    else os.path.dirname(
        os.path.dirname(
            os.path.dirname(
                os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.dirname(
                        inspect.getsourcefile(os.environ["wsgi.errors"].__class__)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

```py
lib_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib")

google_cloud_sdk_appengine = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(appengine_python_sdk))

non_venv_site_packages = os.path.dirname(inspect.getsourcefile(io))

google_cloud_sdk_appengine_lib = os.path.join(google_cloud_sdk_appengine, "lib")


def all_pkgs_for_dir(p):
    return map(
        partial(os.path.join, p),
        filter(
            lambda p: (lambda parts: parts[1] == "-" and parts[2][0].isdigit())(
                p.rpartition("-")
            ),
            listdir(p),
        ),
    )


app_yaml_libraries = (
    lambda g: [p[len(g) :].partition("-")[0] for p in sys.path if p.startswith(g)]
)(google_cloud_sdk_appengine_lib + os.path.sep)
```

Then construct the `new_sys_path` with the paths in the right order:

```py
new_sys_path = list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        (
            (
                getcwd(),
                appengine_python_sdk,
                os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(appengine_python_sdk)),
                non_venv_site_packages,
                os.path.join(non_venv_site_packages, "lib-dynload"),
            ),
            (
                # Use new dependencies from `lib` dir if found
                os.path.join(lib_dir, lib_p)
                for lib_p in os.listdir(lib_dir)
                if not lib_p.endswith(".dist-info")
                and lib_p.partition("-")[0] in app_yaml_libraries
            ),
            (
                lib_dir,
                site_packages,
                google_cloud_sdk_appengine_lib,
            ),
        )
    )
)

sys.path = deepcopy(new_sys_path)
google.__path__ = deepcopy(new_sys_path)
deque(map(site.addsitedir, new_sys_path), maxlen=0)
```

If anyone has a less hacky solution I'm all ears …

FYI: Currently debugging a `ImportError: No module named six` error, even though `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(lib_dir, "six.py"))`